# update conference events in twilio

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

i am facing some issue with while transferring the call . Say "user A" and "user B" are in a call and there is a need to connect "user C" . 
 
i have successfully join "user C" in the conference BUT as soon as i kick the 'user A' or 'user B' from the conference COMPLETE conference come to an end .
i need the conference to continue even if i kick a user (either A or B) from conference . 
I have set the conference event

> 'endConferenceOnExit' => 'true'

, between  A and B . i just need to update the conference event between A and B after  connecting the "user C" . 
'endConferenceOnExit' => 'true' is Keep true because i want to end the call if A and B are only in conference and there is no third user here "user C"

I am using twilio SDK with laravel framework

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set `'endConferenceOnExit' => 'true'` for the participants then [when they leave the conference it will end](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-endConferenceOnExit). I would recommend setting `endConferenceOnExit` to `false`, particularly for the use case of tranferring calls like this.

If you absolutely need that set for the portion that A and B are on the call on their own, then you will likely need to move them to a new `<Conference>` before bringing C in.

Comment: At initials point of time its not fix whether we need to join "user C" , so 'endConferenceOnExit' => 'true' is need in the case if there is no "user C" .

Comment: So you might have to transfer user A and B to a different `<Conference>` then, as this is not going to work with that initial setup.